# Is there a way to limit DB entries in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a free version of my app and only allow 3 entries to be made into the database. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to prevent outside applications/users from adding more entries, or are you only concerned about entries that your app makes?

Answer (score 3):

Since it is your own application, you could just count the number of entries in the DB table in question. If it is > 3, then just don't do the insertion.

The query could be something simple like

```
 SELECT COUNT(someCol) FROM myTable
```